# Proper way to get properties with Kotlin-script config for Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin

I have a property in `gradle.properties`:

```
answer = 42
```

Which is used in `build.gradle`:

```
println "answer is ${answer}"
```

Now I want to replace Groovy with Kotlin-script for Gradle configuring. How to access properties in a proper way? What I'm doing now in `build.gradle.kts` is:

```
fun property(name: String) = properties[name] as String

println("answer is " + property("answer"))
```

Which does not seem to be very convenient. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `properties[name]`? If Kotlin script would let you access variables not declared in the script itself, it would not be very safe. This is one of the reasons I'd prefer Kotlin script over Groovy.

Answer (score 8):

Try [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html), like this:

```
val answer by project
println("answer is $answer")
```

There is example in gradle script kotlin repo
https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples/project-properties

Comment: Problem here is that casting doesn't work with delegates. Any? is returned. To get a String you will need to call `answer as String`.

Comment: Specify a concrete type: val answer:String by project